# Quick way to .Trim in presence of many .Children: is there such a command?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, nodes, trim, vba

I do not fully understand the structure of Trim(), when applied to data scraping for websites.

I scrape data called `Elements` from a website, identifying the corresponding node (it is a div class= "a-b" node) and using

```
Set Elements = Document.getElementsByClassName("a-b")
```

As the given node has just 2 subnodes, I use

```
data1 = Trim(Element.Children(1).Children(0).innerText)
    data2 = Trim(Element.Children(1).Children(1).innerText)
```

to arrive at the data I am searching for.

My question is: if the node has X subnodes, and I have to use Trim(), is there a quick way to consider all subnodes at once? I am thinking about a command with the possibility to set up a range of subnodes. I would like to avoid writing Trim() enumerating all Children.

If no such command exists, what should I do?

Thanks a lot!
Avitus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Trim function for VBA is **Function Trim(String)**. 
It accepts **variant/string** and if the string is null, null is returned.
if the node has X subnodes and you want to trim all then you will have loop through all nodes in element.

You can use the **regex** instead and trim all the nodes at once.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. What do you mean with looping through all nodes? Could you please provide me with a little example? Avitus

Comment: here is an example .  Set tblTr = Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each tblTd In tblTr
        Data1 = Trim(tblTd.innerText)
    Next